# How to create a keras layer with a custom gradient in TF2.0?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

since in TensorFlow 2.0 they plan on unifying all high-level APIs under keras (which I'm not much familiar with) and removing Sessions altogether, I was wondering:

**How can I create a custom keras layer that has a custom gradient?**

I've seen the (quite limited) [guide](https://keras.io/layers/writing-your-own-keras-layers/) on creating custom layers in keras but it doesn't describe what we should do if we want our operation to have a custom gradient.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

First of all, the "unification" of the APIs (as you call it) under keras doesn't prevent you from doing things like you did in TensorFlow 1.x. Sessions might be gone but you can still define your model like any python function and train it eagerly without keras (i.e. through [tf.GradientTape](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/eager/custom_training_walkthrough))

Now, if you want to build a keras model with a **custom layer** that performs a **custom operation** and has a **custom gradient**, you should do the following:

a) Write a function that performs your custom operation and define your custom gradient. More info on how to do this [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/custom_gradient).

```py
@tf.custom_gradient
def custom_op(x):
    result = ... # do forward computation
    def custom_grad(dy):
        grad = ... # compute gradient
        return grad
    return result, custom_grad
```

Note that in the function you should treat `x` and `dy` as Tensors and **not** numpy arrays (i.e. perform tensor operations)

b) Create a custom keras layer that performs your `custom_op`. For this example I'll assume that your layer doesn't have any trainable parameters or change the shape of its input, but it doesn't make much difference if it does. For that you can refer to the guide that you posted check [this one](https://www.tensorflow.org/beta/tutorials/eager/custom_layers).

```py
class CustomLayer(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self):
        super(CustomLayer, self).__init__()

    def call(self, x):
        return custom_op(x)  # you don't need to explicitly define the custom gradient
                             # as long as you registered it with the previous method
```

Now you can use this layer in a keras model and it will work. For example:

```py
inp = tf.keras.layers.Input(input_shape)
conv = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(...)(inp)  # add params like the number of filters
cust = CustomLayer()(conv)  # no parameters in custom layer
flat = tf.keras.layers.Flatten()(cust)
fc = tf.keras.layers.Dense(num_classes)(flat)

model = tf.keras.models.Model(inputs=[inp], outputs=[fc])
model.compile(loss=..., optimizer=...)  # add loss function and optimizer
model.fit(...)  # fit the model
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I thought keras classes needed to have a `grad`-like method that performs the backward computation.

Comment: Thanks for the answer here. Can you look at this related post? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58223640/custom-activation-with-custom-gradient-does-not-work

Comment: Even if I define my function like what you had said above and run it, I don't see the effect of gradient = zero as the loss changes every time.

Comment: The loss that keras shows is something like a moving average of the losses of each batch, i.e. it differs depending on the order you present the batches to your model. Add a validation set and check the val_loss to see if that changes from epoch to epoch.