# Compute gradients in a custom layer in Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, google-colaboratory, keras-layer

I have written a code that computes Choquet pooling in a Custom Layer in Keras. Below the Colab link to the notebook:
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1lCrUb2Jm680JRnACPxWpxkOSkP_DlHGj
As you can the code crashes in gradient computation, precisely inside the function custom_grad. This is impossible because I'm returning 0 gradients with the same shape as the previous layer.
So I have 2 questions:

- Is in Keras (or in Tensorflow) a way to compute gradient between the layer input and its output?
- If I have passed a Tensor with the same shape as the previous layer, but filled with 0s, why the code is not working?

Thanks for your attention and I'm waiting for your help. 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

No one is interested in that question. 
After several trials, I have found a solution. The problem is that, as posted by Mainak431 in this GitHub repo:
[link to diff and non-diff ops in tensorflow](https://github.com/Mainak431/List-of-Differentiable--OPs-and-Non-differentiable-OPs--in-Tensorflow)

There are differentiable TensorFlow operations and non-differentiable operations. In the Colab notebook, I used, as an example,  scatter_nd_update that is non-differentiable. 
So I suggest, if you want to create your own Custom Layer in Keras to take a look at the above lists in order to use operations that allow Keras to auto-differentiate for you.
Anyway, I'm working on it to inform as much as possible on that open research topic. I remember that with the neural network the "LEGO-ing" is borderline, and I know for sure that many of you are interested in adding your operations(aggregation or something else) in a deep neural network model. 
Special Thanks to Maniak431, I love you <3

Comment: Maybe this might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56657993/how-to-create-a-keras-layer-with-a-custom-gradient-in-tf2-0/56658149