# Adding a constant to Loss function in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, loss-function

I have asked a similar question but no response. So I try it again,

I am reading a paper which suggest to add some value which is calculated outside of Tensorflow into the loss function of a neural network model in Tensorflow. i show you the quote here (I have blurred the not important part):

[image]

How do I add a precalculated value to the loss function when fitting a sequential Model in Tensorflow?
The Loss function used is BinaryCrossentropy, you can see it in the equation (4) in the paper quote. And the value added is shown in the quote but it is not important for the question i think.

**It is also not important how my model looks like, i just want to add a constant value to my loss function in tensorflow when fitting my model.**

Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you want to be able to define your own loss. Also, I am not sure whether you use actual Tensorflow or Keras. Here is a solution with Keras:

```
import tensorflow.keras.backend as K

def my_custom_loss(precomputed_value):
    def loss(y_true, y_pred):
        return K.binary_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred) + precomputed_value
    return loss

my_model = Sequential()
my_model.add(...)
# Add any layer there

my_model.compile(loss=my_custom_loss(42))
```

Inspired from https://towardsdatascience.com/advanced-keras-constructing-complex-custom-losses-and-metrics-c07ca130a618

**EDIT:** The answer was only for adding a constant term, but I realize that the term suggested in the paper is not constant.

I haven't read the paper, but I suppose from the cross-entropy definition that sigma is the ground truth and p is the predicted value. If there are no other dependency, the solution can even be simpler:

```
def my_custom_loss(y_pred, y_true):
    norm_term = K.square( K.mean(y_true) - K.mean(y_pred) )
    return K.binary_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred) + norm_term

# ...

my_model.compile(loss=my_custom_loss)
```

Here, I assumed the expectations are only computed on each batch. Tell me whether it is what you want. Otherwise, if you want to compute your statistics at a different scale, e.g. on the whole dataset after every epoch, you might need to use callbacks. 
In that case, please give more precision on your problem, adding for instance a small example for `y_pred` and `y_true`, and the expected loss.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Like this the 'precomputed_value' is just added for when compiling the data, how would it be possible to do this for every epoch or actually for every mini_batch?

Comment: Here I edited the answer to add some precisions for a non-constant term that only depends on the batch statistics. Is it what you want ?

Comment: Thanks for answering again. Yes you are right sigma is the 'ground truth' however the background of the paper is much more complicated and i tried to bypass explaining it for my question. Maybe it helps if I explain a little bit more. E() is not the expectation value or 'mean' as you have written. It is the Energy. The Energy can be calculated by a more difficult algorithm. I am not sure how to implement this in the backend kind of way.

Comment: And p is also a little bit more complicated. Yes it is the prediction, but it needs to be processed in another step to calculate the energy here. The prediction is a float between 0 and 1 and is actually symbolizing the probability to be 0 or 1. So in the end it is a binary number. Think of it as Schroedingers cat, its also a physics paper... Any hint how i can implement this? or how this quote of the paper is meant?

Comment: The more you give information from the beginning, the easier it is to help you. Have you written code to compute that energy term? Can you share it by editing your question? You can also share a link to the paper you mentioned.

Comment: Finally, if the algorithm is too complicated to be written as a combination of basic primitives, maybe you want to compute the gradient yourself, and implement it in a separate function. I have never done this before, but here's a pointer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56657993/how-to-create-a-keras-layer-with-a-custom-gradient-in-tf2-0

Answer (score 1):

In the equation above as you can see, there can a chance when the outcome is very low i.e. the problem of vanishing gradient may occur.

In order to alleviate that, they are asking to add a constant value to the loss.

Now, you can a simple constant such 1, 10 or anything, or by something proportional to what they have said.

You can easily calculate the expectation from the ground truth for one part. The other part is the tricky one as you won't have values until you train and calculating them on the fly is not wise.

That term means how much difference between the ground truth and predictions will be there.

So, if you are going to implement this paper, then, add a constant value of 1 to your loss, so it doesn't vanish.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but something is still unclear. When adding the constant value of 1 to the loss function, how is this influencing the gradient? Isn't the gradient, the derivation of the loss and a adding a constant would in this sense not change a thing in this manner.

Comment: It doesn't change a thing about gradients, it is only to protect your gradients from vanishing.

Comment: Isnt this a contradiction? How does adding a constant to your loss prevent the gradients from vanishing? A gradient is a derivation of the loss function and the derivation of a constant is zero.

Comment: Yes, gradient is a derivation of the rate of change of weights but what happens if that comes out to be zero, then, what will be backpropagated will be that zero and it will start diminishing the weights of the whole network. Learning will thus stop. So, you add something to a loss which keeps it up, because maybe this batch or epoch has gone bad, but next time when data flows through it, weights may recover. It is giving a fair chance to your network to bounce back.

Comment: I think you understood something wrong. Any backpropagation algorithm is considering the derivation of the loss function and not of the derivation of the 'rate of change of weights'. The last one would be the Laplace operator. As i understood it: it does not matter for the backpropagation algorithm if you have a loss value of 1 million or of 1. What matter is the difference between the loss function between the steps. The Loss function needs to be derived for a backpropagation algorithm to work and the derivation of a constant is zero. Therefore adding any constant does not help for anything.

Comment: Ok. Let's see here suppose, you have loss = MSE + 1, every single time you will compute this, 1 will be added to it. Now, the gradients will be derived from the loss, that's for sure. But, this 1 always remains. It is not doing anything except helping your gradients from drowning into lower values.