# Custom layer uses function with @tf.custom_gradient throws error: decorator currently supports arguments only when eager execution is enabled

Tags: machine-learning, python-3.7, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

python == 3.7.6
Tensorflow = 2.0.0

I've created a custom layer which calls a function decorated with @tf.custom_gradient, very similar to the situation described by the answer under the following question:
[How to create a keras layer with a custom gradient in TF2.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56657993/how-to-create-a-keras-layer-with-a-custom-gradient-in-tf2-0)

But I keep getting this error at runtime: `ValueError: The custom_gradient decorator currently supports keywords arguments only when eager execution is enabled.`

The function itself runs just fine when called in the main function. So to be explicit:

`output = custom_function(input)` runs just fine with eager execution, but

```
input_tensor = Input(shape=(1, input_length))
output_layer = Custom_Layer(...)(input_tensor)
model = Model([input_tensor], [output_layer])
model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', run_eagerly=True, loss='mae', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.summary()
```

doesn't work at all. I've tried every combination of turning on and off eager execution, including inside the compile command as shown and inside the call function of the layer and at the top of the script using `tf.config.experimental_run_functions_eagerly(True)`, but nothing stops the error from appearing.

I cannot seem to find any documentation related to this occurrence.

Answer (score 2):

I solved this issue just by moving the functional parts of my `@tf.custom_gradient` function inside of a `tf.keras.layer`. By tweaking my input values a bit and studying more about `tf.GradientTape` mechanics I managed to get my system to work.