# Tensorflow custom layer with backpropagation

Tags: python, tensorflow2.0

I want to create the custom keras layer in Tensorflow. For instance, custom activation layer based on sigmoid function with trainable parameters **a** and **b**, so my function looks like:
1 / (1 + exp(a*x + b)).
I looked into Tensorflow tutorials, but they address custom layers derived from already existing layers. So, the question is How can I implement the desired functionality?

The functionality is provided for example purposes. In general, the question targets creation of custom tensorflow.keras layer with trainable parameters (weights).

Answer (score 0):

To "implement backpropagation", you need to provide the gradient of an operator so that the gradient of the outputs with respect to the inputs (in short gradient) can be computed.

### Custom layer definition (with no variables/parameters)

If you are using simple operations, there is no need to define the gradients (for example if you are using math functions). If you really want to create a custom layer and define its gradient, you have this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56657993/how-to-create-a-keras-layer-with-a-custom-gradient-in-tf2-0).

### Custom layer definition (with variables/parameters)

I wont define the gradient of my custom layer. If you have variables, the code below provide an example:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Layer
from tensorflow.keras.activations import tanh

class Stanh(Layer):
    """Self scalable tanh reference : https://arxiv.org/pdf/2204.12589.pdf

    :param units: number of neurons at a given layer
    :kind units: int
    """

    def __init__(self, units=1):
        super().__init__()
        beta = tf.ones([1, units], dtype=dtype)
        self.beta = tf.Variable(beta, dtype=dtype, trainable=True)

    def call(self, x):
        tanhx = tanh(x)
        return tanhx + self.beta * x * tanhx

    def get_config(self):
        return {"beta": self.beta.numpy()}
```

It defines the Self-scalable tanh defined in the paper in the docstring of the class. It inherits from the Layer class of Tensorflow which is traced by default. Its trainable variables are defined with tf.Variable(trainable=True). This code has been tested for TF2.11.