# Manually set gradient values in TensorFlow and use them in backpropagation

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, backpropagation, loss-function

Just to make sure this is not an XY problem, I'll describe the situation:

I'm building a NN with keras/TensorFlow, and the loss function I'd like to use appears to be non-differentiable to TF. Wrapping it in `tf.py_function` didn't work, as the gradients were all `None`. This loss is not trivial, and it's written in a completely different framework. I realise the most straightforward way would be to rewrite the loss using tf functions, but this is not feasible (at least right now).

The last layer of the net is a fully connected layer with a softmax output, `tf.keras.layers.Dense(n_labels, activation='softmax')`. Through other means (not tf), I'm able to get the (numeric) gradients of the loss w.r.t. the output of this layer. So this gave me an idea: would it be possible to manually set this gradients in the training phase and then let Tensorflow propagate them to the rest of the net to update the weights? At least in my mind, this would circumvent the problem of the non-differentiable loss, but it is not clear to me whether the loss would actually be optimised or how to code it.

Thanks a lot

Comment: I am not still clear what is the nature of your loss function,but if you want you can define a custom loss function in tf and can use to train model

Comment: `So this gave me an idea: would it be possible to manually set this gradients in the training phase and then let Tensorflow propagate them to the rest of the net to update the weights?`

The problem with this is that `tf.keras` trains in graph mode by default, so it's easy to run into `OperatorNotAllowedInGraph` errors when you stray too far outside the bumpers Keras puts in place. I think the proper question is how to express your loss in tensorflow

Comment: You want to manually calculate the gradients of the final layer and let tf calculate the rest of the gradients?

Comment: @ShubhamShaswat it doesn't work because the function is not differentiable (apparently), so the gradients returned during backprop are all None, and the weights don't get updated

Comment: @Djib2011 exactly, unless there's another way of solving the problem

Comment: You should be able to do that with [`tf.custom_gradient`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/custom_gradient), even if you need to wrap parts or all in [`tf.py_function`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/py_function) or [`tf.numpy_function`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/numpy_function).

Comment: for a non differentiable function,you can't use back propagation but have you tried some way to make the function differentiable,if I am not wrong they use some approach to make variational auto encoder differentiable too

Comment: I think you should be able to use [`apply_gradients`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/optimizers/Optimizer#apply_gradients) method of optimizer as well by passing your computed gradients.

Comment: @jdehesa thanks, but I'm not completely sure how to do that

Comment: @ShubhamShaswat it would be very time-consuming to make the loss differentiable, since a simple wrap in `tf.py_function` didn't work.

Comment: Please provide more information

Comment: @bernie create a [layer with a custom gradient](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56658149/5668710) where you set the value of the gradient manually. Then tf will backpropagate that value to the previous layers.

Answer (score 2):

You are not really giving much detail, but as a general idea, you can use [`tf.custom_gradient`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/custom_gradient) and [`tf.numpy_function`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/numpy_function) or [`tf.py_function`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/py_function) to compute the value and the gradient of your operation out of TensorFlow (at the expense of some overhead, plus the limitations stated in the documentation of those functions). For example, something like this:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

# Some operation that you can only compute with NumPy
def my_operation_np(x):
    return np.square(x)

# The gradient of the operation computed with NumPy too
def my_operation_grad_np(x, y, dy):
    # In this example you could also pass only `x` here and
    # do the `* dy` bit in the TensorFlow gradient function.
    # That might reduce the amount of memory transfer between
    # TensorFlow and NumPy.
    return np.multiply(2, x) * dy

# TensorFlow wrapper for the operation
@tf.custom_gradient
def my_operation(x):
    y = tf.numpy_function(my_operation_np, [x], x.dtype)
    def grad(dy):
        return tf.numpy_function(my_operation_grad_np, [x, y, dy], x.dtype)
    return y, grad

# Test
with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
    x = tf.constant([1., 2., 3.])
    tape.watch(x)
    y = my_operation(x)
g = tape.gradient(y, x)
tf.print(g)
# [2 4 6]
```