# Tensorflow: how to modify the backpropagation in a layer N

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, backpropagation, custom-training

I would need to do a kind of custom backpropagation so that, in an arbitrary layer of the network I can decide if actually modify the weights going outside that layer, or make them unchanged.
For example: I would like to study what happens if, during training, I force to not update some weight connecting input layer to 1st layer.

Is there a simple way to just "correct" the normal backpropagation intersecting between the layers ?

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create a keras layer with a custom gradient in TF2.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56657993/how-to-create-a-keras-layer-with-a-custom-gradient-in-tf2-0)

Comment: Actually, not so much, I need something really more simple than that. I just want to manipulate the update of the weights connecting input layer with first layer, where with manipulate I mean choose if update or not.