# Error when defining custom gradients in Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, gradient

I have been trying to define a custom layer in Keras with a custom discrete gradient, as the activation function is discrete.

The layer looks like this:

```py
class DiffLayer(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self):
        super(DiffLayer, self).__init__()

    def build(self, input_shape):
        self.w = self.add_weight(
            shape=(15, 1),
            initializer="random_normal",
            trainable=True,
        )

        self.b = self.add_weight(
            shape=(1, 1), initializer="random_normal", trainable=True
        )

    def call(self, x):
        z = tf.matmul(Flatten()(x), self.w) + self.b
        a = custom_op(z)
        self.a = a
        if K.greater(a,0.5):
            return x-1
        else: 
            return x
```

And the `custom_op` function:

```
@tf.custom_gradient
def custom_op(x):
    a = 1. / (1. + K.exp(-x))
    def custom_grad(dy):
        if K.greater(a, 0.5):
          grad = K.exp(x)
        else:
          grad = 0
        return grad
    return a, custom_grad
```

I have followed the tutorials from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56657993/how-to-create-a-keras-layer-with-a-custom-gradient-in-tf2-0) but when I try to fit the network that I am working with I get the following warning:

> WARNING:tensorflow:Gradients do not exist for variables ['diff_layer_10/Variable:0', 'diff_layer_10/Variable:0'] when minimizing the loss.

My guess is that Keras is not detecting the defined gradient because of the way it is defined but I cannot think of a different way of defining it.

Is this the case or am I missing something in my code?

**EDIT**

As suggested by one of the comments I am going to further explain what I am trying to do. I want `a` to be a parameter that decides what happens to the input data. If `a` is greater than 0.5 then I want 1 subtracted to the input data, otherwise the layer should return the input data.

I do not know if that is possible to do in Keras.

Comment: In your op, `z = f(x)` and `a = g(z) = g(f(x))` but then you just return `x`. There is nothing to differentiate. If you can edit your question and explain what your goals is can help you refactor your code.

Comment: Sorry, I have tried to be more specific with an edit.

Comment: I understand `a > 0.5` then returning `x-1`, what I am saying is what is the objective of your model? What is it your network is trying to do? If I can understand that, I could probably help you design this layer in a better way. I would make sure you understand what a neural network does in terms of calculus/chain rule before using them.